# Why is this div adding empty space at the bottom?

Tags: html, css, space

I have the following code:

```
<div class="line">
<div class="content">Hello, How are you?</div>
```

CSS:

```
 .line {
 border-bottom: 1px solid tomato;
 margin: 30px auto;
 width: 852px;
 overflow: hidden;
 }

 .content {
 color: #000;
 font-size: 15;
 }
```

The .line class is adding space in between the line and the content below it.  I am not sure why.  What can I do to fix this?

Comment: Also, include a unit for the `font-size` property

Comment: @Yana You mean a unit :p

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`margin: 30px auto;` evaluates to

```
margin: 30px auto 30px auto;
```

That is, `30px` on top, and `30px` on bottom. Hence the spacing.

If you dont want the space, you can do

```
margin: 30px auto 0;
```

Or

```
margin: 30px auto 0 auto;
```

Comment: The solution, therefore, is to use `margin: 30px auto 0;`

Comment: Thank you :) Was editing to `margin: 30px auto 0 auto;` yours was better.

Comment: Thanks! I never knew about that.  Now I know, thanks @karthikr